# How to let a background-image inside the parent div with radius border

Tags: css

I have parent div. This parent div has some border radius. Inside this div I have a child div. This child div has a background image. How can add some css styling, so the background image will be inside the parent div radius borders?

```
<div class="zc-normalradius zc-bgcolor-normal singleLink">
            <div id="singleLinkPicture" class="singleLinkPicture" />
</div>
```

Comment: That will happen automatically. If you add a border radius to a div with a background image, the image is treated the same way as the div.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `overflow: hidden` to the parent `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/b4Ld4fg6/.  Or, you can make the child `div` `inherit` the `border-radius` of the parent.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div > div {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1000x1000)
                no-repeat
                center center/cover;
}
```